# Определить - это поворот или нет

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Начинаю свой путь с машинном обучении и столкнулся с первыми трудностями. Задача - научить определять модель по координатам и повороту смартфона является ли это поворотом или нет. Данные координат и поворота смартфона есть.

Какую модель выбрать и как лучше с ней работать?

Данные для примера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для начала нужно определиться что такое поворот.

Comment: В данной постановке задача непонятна. Нужно больше деталей. И картинок.

Comment: Так то можно хоть логистическую регрессию для начала взять. Я только не пойму - у вас нет целевой переменной, чтобы обучить модель где поворот, а где нет?

Comment: Подобрать оптимальную модель сразу вряд ли получится, пробуйте различные и сравнивайте результаты их работы. Вопрос "как лучше с ней работать" не очень понятен. Прочитайте какую-нибудь книгу по ML, там описывается всё подробно.